# How can i create an responsive app to all sizes in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm really confused about this, i've been working with linearlayout only and apparently it's not responsive to all screen sizes, i looked online about some solutions and i found that people usually create diffrent xml files for diffrent screen sizes which seems like alot of work, is there any other way for doing that without going throught all of that trouble ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try using other layouts, arbitrary options for designing a scalable interface, such as ConstraintLayout, you would design probably based on the aspect ratio of the screen, there are a few things. will help you, Chain, GuildeLine, .... All of it is in ConstraintLayout
More information about ConstraintLayout from Google:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout.

Some special screens need separate layouts such as Tablet, .....

Answer (score -1):

best solution for doing this is constraint layout by using can build your responsive ui .
you can find some tutorials for using this layout in youtube .
or you can use google tutorial in android developer site.